# jQuery appends blank (nothing) when concatenating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html

```
<html>
  <head>        
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/rest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody id="list"></tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = 'js/context.xml'
requestXML(url);
});

function requestXML(url){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            var items = $(xml).find('item');
            $.each(items, function(){
                var id = $(this).text();
                $('#list').append('<tr>'+id+'</tr>');
                //$('#list').append(id);            
                console.log(id);
            });                 
        }
    });
}
```

When I check the source generated by this, everything  and  is blank. However the console shows all the id. 
If I remove the  tags it shows me all the ids.

what is the problem and how to fix  this.

Comment: Well, `tr` takes child `td`, tried that?

Comment: `$('#list').append('<tr><td>'+id+'</td></tr>');`? also what is the xml structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tymeJV said: put the `id`s into `<td>`s first and then into `<tr>`s:

```
$('#list').append('<tr><td>'+id+'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: ahhh. So stupid. I got so wrapped up in this problem that I could not see that. Thanks guys.